# Verifical qual é a variável com valor maior retornando a variável não o valor

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como retornar a variável de número maior mas não o valor e sim qual é maior.

Por exemplo:

```
$valor_01 = 6;
$valor_02 = 4;
$valor_03 = 3;
$valor_04 = 9;
$valor_05 = 8;
$valor_06 = 5;

echo max($valor_01, $valor_02, $valor_03, $valor_04, $valor_05, $valor_06);

// OUTPUT EXIBIDO
// 9

// OUTPUT DESEJADO PARA CONTROLE
// VAR $valor_04
```

Vou utilizar essa variável para controles `if`, mas preciso saber qual é a variável maior e não o valor.

Se alguém saber como montar mesmo que de outra forma, agradeço.

Comment: explique melhor a necessidade de saber o nome da variável

Comment: O seu problema provavelmente já começa por estar usando várias variáveis ao invés de um *array*. Aprenda usar o recurso correto e não terá que lidar com isto. Você não ganha nada fazendo isto, nem mesmo aprendizado.

Comment: MoisesGame, eu dei a resposta que você precisa. Foi o que você perguntou. Mas dependendo do que você precisa fazer em sua aplicação, poderá usar outro método. Nesse caso você poderia nos explicar o que precisa e nós podemos te dar alternativas. Eu ganhei aprendizado com essa pergunta, mesmo que por curiosidade, saber como imprimir o nome de uma variável. Vou usar um dia ? Não sei. Mas é bom saber. E com certeza você ganha aprendizado também.

Comment: @PedroLaini Quero o retorno da variável maior e não o valor. Se a variável `$valor_04` é a maior. Quero usar ela depois em um `if` por exemplo `if ($variavel_maior > $variavel_atual)` . Tentei ser mais claro =]

Comment: Moises, pela sua resposta de agora, é possível você fazer de outra forma o que quer, sem ser por esse caminho que não é o mais recomendado.

Comment: @DiegoSouza como poderia fazer? Estou fazendo assim porque esse valores vem de consultas no banco, uma de cada consulta diferente. Se poder me ajudar agradeceria muito.

Comment: Como esses valores vem do banco de dados ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza São 6 consultadas separadas, cada uma de uma data. Cada consulta retorna 2 valores diferentes que são somados em uma variável. Um exemplo `$total_data_01 = ( round( $dados_data_01["LIGACOES"] * 0.7 ) + round( $dados_data_01["CONTATOS"]  * 0.8 ) );`

Comment: @DiegoSouza por isso uso em variáveis, tenho que tratar os valores delas depois ainda.

Comment: @MoisesGama as únicas soluções corretas para seu problema é a do Pedro Laini e do Daniel Gregatto. Aprenda fazer do jeito certo. Se tem algo que ele pode melhorar, coloque um comentário na resposta dele, mas não adote soluções erradas. Se bem que elas poderiam ser simplificadas.

Comment: @MoisesGama Eu respondi sua pergunta para o propósito que você precisa, mas em caso de coleções ou sequências, eu recomendo o uso de **array**, não só pela questão de uso de memória, mas pela vantagem de organização e compreensão do código.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Sua reposta atendeu o que precisa. Muito obrigado! Você comentou para utilizar `array` como sua resposta poderia de adaptar em um `array `, poderia fazer um exemplo em sua reposta? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não sei exatamente para o que você precisa, mas você pode fazer isso:

```
<?php

$valor_01 = 6;
$valor_02 = 4;
$valor_03 = 3;
$valor_04 = 9;
$valor_05 = 8;
$valor_06 = 5;

echo '$'.max(explode(', $','$valor_01, $valor_02, $valor_03, $valor_04, $valor_05, $valor_06'));
```

E neste caso se precisa capturar o valor da maior variável, basta utilizar variável variante:

```
$var = max(explode(', $','$valor_01, $valor_02, $valor_03, $valor_04, $valor_05, $valor_06'));
echo $$var;
```

Só que o ideal, quando se trata de uma coleção, é não fazer uso numérico em variáveis. Neste caso, utilize `array()`:

```
$valor[1] = 6;
$valor[2] = 4;
$valor[3] = 3;
$valor[4] = 9;
$valor[5] = 8;
$valor[6] = 5;

//pega a maior índice
echo max(array_keys($valor));
//pega o valor do maior índice
echo $valor[max(array_keys($valor))];
```

Comment: Obrigado Ivan, sua reposta ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que deva controlar isso da seguinte maneira:

```
$array[0] = 2;
$array[1] = 7;
$array[2] = 3;
$array[3] = 4;
$array[4] = 5;

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value > $val_max) {
        $key_max = $key;
        $val_max = $value;
    }
}

//Maior valor || maior array;
echo $array[$key_max];
```

Comment: Esse retorna 7, ou seja, o valor e não o key do array. Sabe como retornar o key?

Answer (score 1):

```
$array[0] = 6;
$array[1] = 4;
$array[2] = 3;
$array[3] = 9;
$array[4] = 8;
$array[5] = 5;

$index = -1
$max_value = $array[0];

for ($i = 1; $i <= count($array); $i++) {
    if($array[$i] > $max_value){
      $max_value = $array[$i];
      $index = $i;
    }
}

//aqui você tem o index do array onde está a variável com max_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja como funciona essa função.

```
<?php

function ShowVar($var) {
    foreach($GLOBALS as $varName => $value) {
        if ($value === $var) {
            return $varName;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$valor_01 = 6;
$valor_02 = 4;
$valor_03 = 3;
$valor_04 = 9;
$valor_05 = 8;
$valor_06 = 5;

$result = max($valor_01, $valor_02, $valor_03, $valor_04, $valor_05, $valor_06);

echo '$'.ShowVar($result);
```

> Return 
>   $valor_04

Comment: Obrigado Diego, vou guardar sua função muito obrigado.